# Why does JavaScript alert display an empty string in Phonegap Android App while the code is working perfectly fine on browser?

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, cordova

I'm working on a simple PhoneGap application that communicates with a server that runs PHP, gets a string and displays it in JavaScript alert.

The App works perfectly fine on a browser. The JavaScript alert displays the string returned by the PHP code on the server. This action happens on click event of a button.

**Here is the markup**:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;">
        <title>PhoneGap</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <button id="eventfire">Click</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#eventfire").click(function(){
    var data = {
        "action": "test"
    }; 
    data=$.parseJSON('{ "name": "John" }');
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            url: "http://192.168.x.x/HelloWorldTest/response.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            alert("type is " + typeof data + ". Length is " + data.length);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.statusText);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    },
             statusCode: {
        400: function    () {
            alert("Bad request!");
        },
        401: function() {
            alert("Unauthorized!");
        },
        403: function() {
            alert("Forbidden!");
        },
        404: function() {
            alert("Page not found!");
        },                
        408: function() {
            alert("Request Timeout!");
        },
        200: function() {
            alert("page reached");
        },    
    }
        }); 
    });

})
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php
echo 'john';
?>
```

When I run this code on a AVD, the alert does not display the string. I have never seen such a alert getting displayed. The alert displayed inside the success function is shown below.

[image: Alert with empty string]

On inspecting this string, I understood that the length is 0.

[image: String Length]

I was able to reproduce the same issue on browser with a string of 0 characters length.

I'm not sure why the piece of code that is working fine when run on browser but acts weirdly on AVD. The string was getting displayed as expected on browser but not on AVD.

Find below the screenshots of the same code displaying the correct alert on browser.

[image: Availability of Service]
[image]

I want to know the possible reasons of why the string from PHP is getting lost ?

Comment: Might sound crazy. But are you sure the Android Device is able to get the response.php file? Could you try to the get the response.php directly to see if it works?

Comment: Yeah. Accessing response.php is giving me the intended string. Added screenshots to the question.

Comment: just to be sure. You accessed it with the android device, right?

Comment: Since your php file is remote, did you set `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in your server's   `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Did you try a different dataType-property for instance html or json? I think "text" as dataType might not be supported by jquery.

Comment: @DelightedD0D - No,I have not. The service is running on localhost and the IP is of my machine. How do I locate and edit it ? I'm on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @Blauharley - Tried html. But still the same issue.

Comment: @barbarity - I tried it on a emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used PhoneGap but since your php file is stored on a different server than the files trying to call it, you will need to enable [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) (though I can't be sure this is the only issue)

---

**Try adding `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in your server's `.htaccess` file**

By default, servers block access to resources like php files when the request comes from a file that is not stored on the same server.

For example, if I have a `js` file located at `http://myfirstwebsite.com/awesome.js` and in that file I make an ajax call to `http://mysecondwebsite.com/loadstuff.php`, the request will be blocked by the server and will produce the following error in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mysecondwebsite.com/loadstuff.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mysecondwebsite.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

***I'm not sure if you can see this error in PhoneGap or where as I have never used it.***

As the warning alludes to, in order to fix this, you must set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to allow remote files to access the ones on your server.

---

[Here is a tutorial explaining how to do that on Ubuntu](https://harthur.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/configure-apache-to-accept-cross-site-xmlhttprequests-on-ubuntu/)

Just in case that link ever dies, here are the steps (copied right from that site)

1. Make sure you have the mod_headers Apache module installed. to do this check out /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ and see if there’s a ‘headers.load’ in there. If there isn’t then just sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/headers.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/headers.load
2. Add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to all HTTP responses. You can do this by adding the line Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" to the desired  section in your configuration file (like the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file). Saying "*" will allow cross-site XHR requests from anywhere. You can say "www.myothersite.com" to only accept requests from that origin.
3. Reload apache server. sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload

Comment: As suggested by you in the question's comment, I added Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" to .htaccess. I created this .htaccess file and placed it in my site's root directory and it started to work. Then, I removed the .htacess file from that folder but my app continued to work. Not sure what happened there. Will try what you have suggested here and let you know. Thanks !

Comment: If you could add your comment to the answer, I will accept it as answer.